# Hello, I have been trying to get a total sum for charges of both students but have been unsuccessful

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I am trying to get total charges for both students together into on cell in a table.I have tried using sum() but still nothing correctly totaling.

```
  <students>
     <student id="001234" type="grad">
     <lastname>Jones</lastname>
     <firstname>Alan</firstname>
     <gpa>3.51</gpa>
     <charges><!--charges-->
         <tuition>1200</tuition>
         <parking>35.20</parking>
         <health>18.50</health>
     </charges>
  </student>

      <student id="001887" type="undergrad">
      <lastname>Chong</lastname>
      <firstname>Susan</firstname>
      <gpa>2.51</gpa>
      <charges>
          <tuition>1645</tuition>
          <activity>50.20</activity>
          <parking>35.20</parking>
          <health>22.50</health>
      </charges>
   </student>
```

Comment: show how you're using `sum()`

Comment: i've tried different ways like sum(//charges), sum(//tuition,//activity...

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
sum(/students/student/charges/*)
```

---

If you're in the context of `students`, then:

```
sum(student/charges/*)
```

will suffice.